# RPi 3B -- LIRC won't setup device: could not get file information for /dev/lirc0

Tags: drivers, raspberry-pi, lirc, ir

Very new to this low-level driver stuff, so many places to make mistakes.
Basically I'm trying to get an IR transmitter with lirc. I have a IR led to pin 23 with a transistor, however there's nothing in `/dev/lirc` or `/dev/lirc0`

I installed lirc with `apt-get install lirc`,

then added `dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_out_pin=23,gpio_in_pin=22` to `config.txt` and changed `lirc_options.conf` to

```
driver          = default
device          = /dev/lirc0
```

However, there's nothing in `/dev`, and if I try to send with `irsend` I get `hardware does not support sending`. The system status for lircd shows this error:

```
Error: could not get file information for /dev/lirc0
```

I'm using a RPi 3B running Raspbian Stretch with `Linux raspberrypi 4.19.42-v7+ #1219` firmware.

I don't know what other command dump you might need so just comment and I'll add to the question

NOTE: I was reading about `gpio-ir` however that seems to be receiver only. Any link to any library with IR transmission would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems in newer Kernel `lirc-rpi` doesnt exist anymore in `/boot/overlays/`.
I found in `/boot/overlays/README` that we have to use `gpio-ir` (Receiver) or/ and `gpio-ir-tx` (Transmitter) instead of `lirc-rpi`

For me it helped to change:

```
dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_out_pin=23,gpio_in_pin=22
```

to:

```
dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=22       #(without: in)
dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=23    #(without: out)
```

At the moment, i have to comment out one of them, because it works either `gpio-ir` OR `gpio-ir-tx`, not both at the same time (for me).

J

Comment: Can I then use normal LIRC with it? Or do I need some other software?

Comment: Just tried, works like a charm with the normal lirc binary

Answer (score 0):

I have `uname -a` that gives 
`Linux Hostname 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux`

and after adding this line to `/boot/config.txt` and rebooting

```
dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_in_pin=22,gpio_out_pin=23
```

I finally got a `/dev/lirc0`

Comment: Now with `Linux Hostname 5.10.63-v7+ #1496 SMP Wed Dec 1 15:58:11 GMT 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux` it no longer works. I had to use `toverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=22       #(without: in)
dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=23    #(without: out)`

Answer (score -1):

I use Lirc for my Smarthome with "fhem" to send signals to TV and to recieve signals from tv-remote to switch some lights.
At the moment I only can send signals. 
My way on fresh and updated STRETCH:

apt-get install lirc ir-keytable

Update the following line in /boot/config.txt:

(#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=27)

dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=23

Update the following lines in /etc/lirc/lirc_options.conf:

driver    = default

device    = /dev/lirc0

install LircClient:

perl -MCPAN -e shell

install Lirc::Client

I am able to use my old recorded lircd.config to send signals to my tv. But I cant use ".lircrc" in the old way, to recieve signals. Perhaps there is someone who knows how to do?
Hope it helps!
J